# How to generate the Present Continuous Tense - The ING Form Of The Verbs?

Tags: python, nlp

I wan to to get the 'ing' form of a verb.

Currently I am using this method which depends on [Nodebox English Linguistics library](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics#verb_conjugation). And my code fails in most cases.

```
from libs.en import *

def get_contineous_tense(i_verb):
    i_verb = verb.infinitive(i_verb) #Make sure that the verb is in infinfinitive form

    temp = i_verb + 'ing'
    if verb.infinitive(temp) ==  i_verb:
        return temp

    temp = i_verb + i_verb[-1:] + 'ing'
    if verb.infinitive(temp) ==  i_verb:
        return temp

    #......... Continues like This


print get_contineous_tense('played')
```

Comment: How does your code fail exactly? E.g. what is the output you get and what is the output you desire instead?

Comment: Looks OK to me (except you misspell "continuous", and I assume you've elided the other cases like "pet"->"petting"). Also, your code assumes that calling infinitive() on a non-word will return a non-word string. Is that a valid assumption?

Comment: @jsalonen When I said my code fails, I meant that I don't know English well and I may not be able to cover all possible cases. Another reason was that NodeBox does not cover all words it contains 10,000 verbs as documented.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Yes, calling infinitive() returns the infinitive form of a verb. However, it can do that for 10,000 verbs and I don't know whether there are more English verbs or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
verb.present_participle(word)
```

This is functionality that comes with NodeBox English Linguistics, documented right in the link you gave.

Comment: Thank you very much. I looked and I could not find it. I did not know that present_participle means ing form. Sorry I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: @K.H.A.: That's understandable, then. Glad I could help.